# d3 Sunburst reduce parent node inner and outer radius on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I am trying to reduce the size of the parent level inner and outer radius' when I click on one of its children nodes. You can view my current diagram here: https://jsfiddle.net/2heLd2b1/. As you can see, when a child node is clicked and the distorts to display the selected node and its path, the parent layers take up too much space. I am looking for any suggestions as to how I could reduce or shrink the parent nodes width.

```
ar width = 960,
    height = 750,
    radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 10;

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, radius]);

function percent(d) {
    var percentage = (d.value / 956129) * 100;
    return percentage.toFixed(2);
}

// var tip = d3.tip()
//   .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
//   .offset([-10, 0])
//   .html(function(d) {
//     return "<strong>" + d.name + "</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + percent(d) + "%</span>";
//   })

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    // .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)) })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)) })
    .cornerRadius(function(d) { return 5;});


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .append("g")
    .classed("inner", true);

// svg.call(tip);

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var g = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(partition.nodes(root))
        .enter().append("g");

    path = g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr('stroke', 'white')
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
        .on("click", magnify)
        // .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        // .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
        .each(stash);

    var text = g.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("dx", "6") // margin
        .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        })
        .attr('font-size', function(d) {
            return '10px';
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            if (d.depth > 0) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")" +
                       "rotate(" + getStartAngle(d) + ")";
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        })
        .on("click", magnify);

    var innerG = d3.selectAll("g.inner");



    // Distort the specified node to 80% of its parent.
    function magnify(node) {

        // get and store parent sequence
        var parentSequence = getAncestors(node)

        text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);
        spin(node);

        // check if node has a parent. If so, iterate throught parentSequence and update the size of each node in the sequence
        if (node.parent) {
            for (var p = 0; p < parentSequence.length; p++) {
                if (parent = parentSequence[p].parent) {
                    var parent,
                        x = parent.x,
                        k = 0.95;
                    parent.children.forEach(function(sibling) {
                        x += reposition(sibling, x, sibling === parentSequence[p]
                          ? parent.dx * k / parentSequence[p].value
                          : parent.dx * (1 - k) / (parent.value - parentSequence[p].value));
                    });
                } else {
                    reposition(parentSequence[p], 0, parentSequence[p].dx / parentSequence[p].value);
                }
            }
        // if node does not have parent (center node) reset all values to original
        } else {
            if (parent = node.parent) {
                var parent,
                    x = parent.x,
                    k = 0.95;
                parent.children.forEach(function(sibling) {
                    x += reposition(sibling, x, sibling === node
                      ? parent.dx * k / node.value
                      : parent.dx * (1 - k) / (parent.value - node.value));
                });
            } else {
                reposition(node, 0, node.dx / node.value);
            }
        }

        path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween)
        .each("end", function(e, i) {

          // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in node
            if (e.x >= node.x && e.x < (node.x + node.dx)) {
            // get a selection of the associated text element
                var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
            // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
                arcText.transition().duration(750)
                .attr("opacity", 1)
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    if (d.depth > 0) {
                        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")" +
                               "rotate(" + getNewAngle(d) + ")";
                    }  else {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function spin(d) {
        var spin1 = new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
            var newAngle = - x(d.x + d.dx / 2);
            // console.log('newAngle', newAngle)

            innerG
                .transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .attr("transform", "rotate(" + ((180 / Math.PI * newAngle)) + ")");
                resolve("Success!");
        });

        spin1.then(function() {
            var newerAngle = - x(d.x + d.dx / 2);
            // console.log('newerAngle', newerAngle)

            innerG
                .transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .attr("transform", "rotate(" + ((180 / Math.PI * newerAngle)) + ")");
        })

        path
            .classed("selected", function (x) { return d.name == x.name; });
    }

    // Recursively reposition the node at position x with scale k.
    function reposition(node, x, k) {
        // console.log(k)
        node.x = x;
        if (node.children && (n = node.children.length)) {
            var i = -1, n;
            while (++i < n) x += reposition(node.children[i], x, k);
        }
        return node.dx = node.value * k;
    }

    // Stash the old values for transition.
    function stash(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.dx0 = d.dx;
    }

    // Interpolate the arcs in data space.
    function arcTween(a) {
        var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
        return function(t) {
            var b = i(t);
            a.x0 = b.x;
            a.dx0 = b.dx;
            return arc(b);
        };
    };
});

function getStartAngle(d) {
    // Offset the angle by 90 deg since the '0' degree axis for arc is Y axis, while
    // for text it is the X axis.
    var thetaDeg = (180 / Math.PI * (arc.startAngle()(d) + arc.endAngle()(d)) / 2 - 90);
    // If we are rotating the text by more than 90 deg, then "flip" it.
    // This is why "text-anchor", "middle" is important, otherwise, this "flip" would
    // a little harder.
    return (thetaDeg > 90) ? thetaDeg - 180 : thetaDeg;
}

function getNewAngle(d) {
    var thetaDeg = (180 / Math.PI * (arc.startAngle()(d) + arc.endAngle()(d)) / 2 - 90);
    return (thetaDeg < 90) ? thetaDeg - 180 : thetaDeg;
}

function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}
```

Comment: I have thought about using a recursive function that would essentially take the node I clicked on and run down its parent path. Once it knows the path it will take all nodes in the layers of this parent path and reduce their inner and outer radius angles. This will be done in reverse when clicking back to an earlier node layer in the hierarchy

Comment: I tried the above and its a pain in the butt. IMHO its much simpler to adjust the inner and outer radius as shown below in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by combining the tween methods from my original jsFiddle link, https://jsfiddle.net/2heLd2b1/, with the traditional tween used by a zoomable sunburst.You can see the implementation here: https://jsfiddle.net/6e4y0s11/

I altered my innerRadius and outerRadius from:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)) })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)) })
    .cornerRadius(function(d) { return 5;});
```

to:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(d.depth * 20, y(d.y)) })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(100, y(d.y + d.dy)) })
    .cornerRadius(function(d) { return 5;});
```

I also added:

```
function arcTweenZoom(d) {
    var yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) {
            y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));
            return arc(d);

        };
  };
}
```

so that I could interpolate the scales. The final result allows the inner parent level nodes to shrink without actually disappearing. The maintain a minimum radius based on their d.y values.